# How to generate more than one border radius

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make shapes with variable border radius.

Based on a modifier the shape should have a border radius of either 50 % (when `Math.random() > 0.5`), 20 % (when `Math.random() > 0.8`), and default to 0 % giving a plain square.

However, when you use the on-click function it will only give either the 20 % radius or the default shape, and not the 50 % radius.

Here is a simplified version of the key method:

```js
function makeShapeAppear() {
    var top = Math.random() * 400;
    var left = Math.random() * 400;
    var width = (Math.random() * 100) + 100;

    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
        document.getElementById("shape").style.borderRadius = "50%"
    } else {
        document.getElementById("shape").style.borderRadius = "0";
    }

    if (Math.random() > 0.8) {
        document.getElementById("shape").style.borderRadius = "20%"
    } else {
        document.getElementById("shape").style.borderRadius = "0";
    }
}
```

The complete code snippet:

```js
var bestTime = 0;

var start = new Date().getTime();

function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

function makeShapeAppear() {
    var top = Math.random() * 400;
    var left = Math.random() * 400;
    var width = (Math.random() * 100) + 100;
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
        document.getElementById("shape").style.borderRadius = "50%"
    } else {
        document.getElementById("shape").style.borderRadius = "0";
    }

    if (Math.random() > 0.8) {
        document.getElementById("shape").style.borderRadius = "20%"
    } else {
        document.getElementById("shape").style.borderRadius = "0";
    }

    document.getElementById("shape").style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
    document.getElementById("shape").style.width = width + "px";
    document.getElementById("shape").style.height = width + "px";
    document.getElementById("shape").style.top = top + "px";
    document.getElementById("shape").style.left = left + "px";
    document.getElementById("shape").style.display = "block";
    start = new Date().getTime();
}

function appearAfterDelay() {
    setTimeout(makeShapeAppear, Math.random() * 2000)
}

appearAfterDelay();

document.getElementById("shape").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("shape").style.display = "none";
    var end = new Date().getTime();
    var timeTaken = (end - start) / 1000;
    document.getElementById("timeTaken").innerHTML = timeTaken + "'s";
    if (timeTaken < bestTime || bestTime == 0) {
        bestTime = timeTaken;
        document.getElementById("best").innerHTML = bestTime + "s"
    }
    appearAfterDelay();
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: azure;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

#shape {
    background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
}

.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}

#best {
    color: limegreen;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <title>Javascript Test You Reactions</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Test Your Reactions!</h1>
    <P>Click on the squares and circles as <em><ins>quickly</ins></em>as you can!</P>
    <p class="bold">Your time: <span id="timeTaken"></span></p>
    <p>Best time: <span id="best"></span></p>
    <div id="shape"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Read through your code and think what it does. You're getting two random numbers and doing things based on them, but only the last one will affect things. You need to rethink your if statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following code for getting the shape radius

```
var  randomNumber = Math.Random();
if (randomNumber > 0.8) {
    document.getElementById("shape").style.borderRadius = "20%";
}
else if (randomNumber > 0.5) {
    document.getElementById("shape").style.borderRadius = "50%";
} else {
    document.getElementById("shape").style.borderRadius = "0";
}
```

Comment: why `Please use` ? :) you may simply right a short explanation instead of telling him to use the code.

Comment: I think the code is simple enough to be self-explanatory . Why should I write  an essay on it just to get an upvote or get my answer accepted ? :)

Answer (score 0):

As shown by [UchihaItachi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6551593/uchihaitachi) your main problem is in the ordering and separation of the conditional statements determining the right border radius; if the random number is over `0.5` but not over `0.8`, the first conditional will set the radius to `50%`, but the second will set it to `0`.
Another little problem is recomputing the random value to test against, which will increase the probability of getting a border radius of `0`.

This can all be improved like this

```
function makeShapeAppear() {
    var top = Math.random() * 400;
    var left = Math.random() * 400;
    var width = (Math.random() * 100) + 100;

    var factor = Math.random();
    var radius = "0";

    if (factor > 0.8) {
        radius = "20%"
    } else if (factor > 0.5) {
        radius = "50%"
    }

    document.getElementById("shape").style.borderRadius = radius;
}
```

The complete code snippet, with a few other changes (e.g. only get the `shape` element once, structure code for readability, direct assignments when possible, etc.):

```js
var bestTime = 0,
    shape = document.getElementById("shape"),
    start = new Date().getTime();

shape.onclick = click;
appearAfterDelay();


function appearAfterDelay() {
    setTimeout(makeShapeAppear, Math.random() * 2000)
}

function click() {
    var end = new Date().getTime(),
        timeTaken = (end - start) / 1000;

    shape.style.display = "none";

    if (timeTaken < bestTime || bestTime == 0) {
        bestTime = timeTaken;
    }

    document.getElementById("timeTaken").innerHTML = timeTaken + "s";
    document.getElementById("best").innerHTML = bestTime + "s"

    appearAfterDelay();
}

function makeShapeAppear() {
    var styles = shape.style,
        factor = Math.random(),
        radius = "0";

    styles.display = "block";
    styles.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
    styles.top = Math.random() * 400 + "px";
    styles.left = Math.random() * 400 + "px";
    styles.width = styles.height = (Math.random() * 100) + 100 + "px";

    if (factor > 0.8) {
        radius = "20%"
    } else if (factor > 0.5) {
        radius = "50%"
    }
    styles.borderRadius = radius;

    start = new Date().getTime();
}

function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: azure;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

#shape {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
}

.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}

#best {
    color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <title>Javascript Test You Reactions</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Test Your Reactions!</h1>
    <p>Click on the squares and circles as <em><ins>quickly</ins></em> as you can!</p>
    <p class="bold">Your time: <span id="timeTaken"></span></p>
    <p>Best time: <span id="best" class="bold"></span></p>
    <div id="shape"></div>
</body>
```